# How to change location of the downloaded maven dependencies?

Tags: maven, grails

While running `grails prod war target/my.war` on Grails 2.5.3, is there a way to change the location to where the maven dependencies get downloaded?

With `maven` there is a variable for this that can be set at command line: `-Dmaven.repo.local=/some/foo/bar/path`

Is there something similar for the `grails prod war target/my.war` command?

Reason I need this is because I am building my application on Jenkins and don't have access to create the `/jslave/.m2/repository/org/grails` folder. So, I need to change the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to use either of the below option in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.dependency.cache.dir = ".path/to/your/custom/repo"
```

or you can also use

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    cacheDir "absolute/path/to/your/custom/repo"
}
```

Refer **[Where are the JARs?](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.3/guide/single.html#mavenIntegration)** for additional details about above and use of Aether vs Ivy.